# Windows Services, ASP.NET webservice + C#

Tags: c#, windows, service, web-services

I have a serious problem (i think ;-)).

We have webservice. A there is a method which we can call A.
We have also a service, which invokes this method from webservice.

On my local computer, invoking A, by service looks good.
On a server, it doesn't work and I get an error like this:

### error: The request failed with the error message:

Object moved

### Object moved to here.

Whats wrong? Web.config file for WS, is the same - on my local computer, and a server.

I don't really have an idea, how to beat this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you typically get when forms authentication tries to redirect unauthenticated users to the login page. Are you sure, your web.config file is correct (forms authentication, access rights to the service)?

Comment: Yes, I had :

<location path="Secured">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    <allow roles="loggedrole2" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>

and change it to

<location path="Secured">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>

And you have to notice, that solution works locally but not on server computer.